# using ddply() function with in for loop in R

Tags: r, plyr

My question is regarding how to use `ddply` in a `for` loop for example.

```
x<-ddply(data, "variable_name", summarize, event= sum(x)/count(x))
```

This is normal `ddply` but what if want I in space of `variable_name` as in the following example:

**

> data

**
 1. `col1,col2,col3,col4`
    `a    x     10   1`
    `a    x     02   2`
    `a    x     40   3`
    `b    x     05   8`
    `b    y     01   10`
    `b    y     08   6`
    `b    y    10    8`
    `b    y     50   6`

`for(i in 1:2){
  result[i]<-ddply(data, name(data[,i]), summarize, event=sum(col3)/count(col4))
}`

```
**
```

> output desired:

** 
    result[col3]

```
 1. col1 event  
     a    17.33  
     b 14.80

result[col4] 

 1. col2 event  
     x    14.25  
     y    17.25
```

---

Comment: Please provide few lines of example and your expected result

Comment: What about this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12917158/loop-over-several-columns-with-ddply

Answer (score 1):

You can always do this with this sort of method (which some may consider hacky):

```
for(i in 1:ncol(data)) {
     q <-sprintf("x <- ddply(data, .(%s), summarize, event=sum(x)/count(x))", 
              names(data)[i]) 
     parse(eval(text = q)) 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

By `sum(.) / count(.)` do you mean the average? I think `summarise` will not work with `count`. If you just want the average I suggest you use `mean` and what you want can be achieved like

```
lapply(c("cyl", "gear"), function(var) ddply(mtcars, var, summarize, mean(mpg)))
#[[1]]
#  cyl      ..1
#1   4 26.66364
#2   6 19.74286
#3   8 15.10000
#
#[[2]]
#  gear      ..1
#1    3 16.10667
#2    4 24.53333
#3    5 21.38000
```

Or equivalently if you want to make use of `names` and indices you can replace the first argument with

```
lapply(names(mtcars)[c(2,10)], ...)
```